# Is it possible to convert a legacy app to UWP using Windows 11 Home?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-11, desktop-app-converter

In an [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/250041/how-to-convert-a-windows-desktop-app-to-a-universal-windows-app/) I've read that Windows 10 Professional is required to use Desktop App Converter. Is this still true for Windows 11?

As I am using Windows 11 Home, will I be required to purchase Windows 11 Professional edition to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Desktop App Converter" has been deprecated. The replacement is the [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/msix-packaging-tool/9n5lw3jbcxkf). The documentation is on [Microsoft Docs](https://aka.ms/MSIX).